# Mapping strings to others in Java

Tags: java, string, comparison

If ud = u , du = d , uu = d , dd = u

And if i get the output "uu du ud" is there a way to get output like this

```
uu du ud  ---Output already got

d  d  u   ---Because uu=d  du=d  ud=u

  u   u   ---Because dd=u  and the other u comes down

    d     ---finally uu=d so the output is d.
```

I have have problems with getting this kind of output ,coz i dont know java much.
The code I had written is

```
public class Test
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

    int count = 0;
    int index = 0;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("How many Line Paremeters?");
    int amount = scan.nextInt();

    // One array to hold all the names
    String[] name = new String[amount];

    System.out.print("You entered "
        + amount + " as the size of your name list.");
    System.out.println(" ");

    // Ask for all the names
    for (index = 0; index < amount; index++)
    {
      System.out.print("Enter Line Paremeters: ");
      name[index] = scan.next();
    }

    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("The order: ");
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println();

    for (String names1 : name)
    {
      System.out.print(names1 + " ");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do the title, the description, and the code have anything to do with each other?

Comment: A little context might help...

Comment: @user1630061 If you can define these steps, then you can do it with Java (or likely any programming language).  It seems like you don't want to actually compare strings, but map them.  My hint for you is to look at java.util.Map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you already have the string "uu du ud" and you want to "reduce" it based on the rule: ud = u , du = d , uu = d , dd = u and any left over characters will "come down" as you put it.  To do that you need to write a recursive function or an iterating loop ( as per comments) that examines the string in chunks of 2 character long substrings and replace as you go according to your rule. I am reluctant to help any further as this does seem to be homework as @DuncanJones asked.

Comment: I suspect that iteration might be simpler.  The OP's example seems to be applying the rewrites in a breadth-first fashion ...

Comment: @StephenC I agree with you iterations would be simpler, It just seemed like a "how to write recursive functions" type of homework hence the suggestion but it could just as well be for simple iteration so I will amend my post accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Strings will be compared for equality using the equals method in Java:

string1.equals(string2)

If you have to compare against a constant string, always put the constant string to the left hand side, this way you don't need to check for Null.

"abc".equals(string3)

Comment: I don't understand how this is relevant to the Question ...

Comment: Well, I would show it directly based on your code. But I find no string compare within.

Comment: @StephenC: well, the original title was "how to compare strings in java" or so.

Comment: @wollud1969 - I see.  So you didn't actually read the question before you answered it?  And you >>still<< think it is what the OP is wanting to know?

Comment: @StephenC: Seems that you are right, I actually just read the title of the question and answered too quick - I have to apologize.